# fancybox shows intermediate state after turn of full screen

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox, rendering, video.js

I have wrote following code:

```
<div class="video-box" id="video-player-div" style="display: none">
    <video id="video-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
           preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
           poster="http://www.ephotobay.com/image/birds-wallpaper-8-chai3721post.jpg"
           data-setup="{}"
           src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">

        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
```

```
<a id="btnForm" href="#video-player-div" title="" class="fancy_image"><img src="/getVideoIcon.png" alt=""></a>
```

---

```
  $("#btnForm").fancybox();
```

When I click full screen and switch of it I see intermediate state(bad):
[image]

and then this(good) [image]

I don't like it.

Please, advise how to fix it!

P.S.

[**Jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/407/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is that your are placing your video as (hidden) *inline* content. Most dynamic *inline* or multimedia content, as is the case of audio, videos and iframes, causes other problems like audio/video still playing in the background after fancybox is closed, etc... not mentioning they may also affect your page load and performance.

I wouldn't advice you to use static HTML *inline* content as you have it but to take another approach and build the HTML content to show in fancybox on-the-fly.

First, target your MP4 media file directly in your link's `href` like :

```
<a id="btnForm" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" title="" class="fancy_image"><img src="/getVideoIcon.png" alt=""></a>
```

**Notice** that with this approach, you could have different links to several videos (using *classes* instead of ID in your selector) and you only need to set the corresponding `href` without having to create a new hidden *inline* content for each new video.

Then, in your fancybox custom initialization script, use callbacks to :

- pre-build the `<video>` content and insert the `href` from the link (`beforeLoad`)
- initialize *video.js* (`beforeShow`)
- remove the *video.js* instance after you are done (`afterClose`).

Here is the code:

```
var player = {}; // global object (so we don't have to initialize several variables)
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#btnForm").fancybox({
        fitToView : false, // keeps fixed video dimensions regardless screen size
        width : 640, // matches size in <video> tag
        height : 264,
        type : "html", // this is important
        autoSize: false, // fixes intermediate state
        beforeLoad : function () {
            // create a random ID :
            player.id = "video-player" + new Date().getTime();
            // pre-build HTML video content :
            player.content =
                '<video id="' + player.id + '" src="' + this.href + '" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="http://www.ephotobay.com/image/birds-wallpaper-8-chai3721post.jpg" data-setup="{}">' +
                '<p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>' +
                '</video>';
            // load video.js flash fallback :
            videojs.options.flash.swf = "{path}/video-js.swf";
            // set fancybox content :
            this.content = player.content;
        },
        beforeShow : function () {
            player.js = videojs(player.id); // initialize video.js
        },
        afterClose : function () {
            $(player.js).remove(); // remove video.js instances
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** we need the combination of `fitToView : false` and `autoSize: false` to eliminate the "intermediate state", but it's important to set dimensions to avoid unexpected results.

And see the [**DEMO**](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancybox_videojs_11feb15.html) (feel free to explore the source code)

Answer (score 0):

From your question i understand that the alignment of the video is stretched. The problem is because of the `custom width('640') and height('264')` you set for the video element. So the fancybox is allocating that much of space to the video element. You need to remove the custom width and height then add a `style= "width:98%;height:auto"` which will solve the issue.

Check the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahendranmails/h9EVQ/412/)